# Login verification always this same redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-2

This is my code:

session_helper

```
if ( ! function_exists('is_login'))
{
    function is_login()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $is_logged_in = $CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != TRUE) { 

            redirect('login');

        }               
    }   
}
```

check_login function

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Check_login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->is_logged_in();  
    }

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $this->load->helper('session_helper');
                $this->load->helper('url');

        is_login();
    }       
}
```

When I induction this function: 
`<?php echo anchor('check_login', 'check', 'class="link-class"') ?>`

Every time is induction `redirect('login');`

I have CI_session table in database, login function is ok.
Where is my problem?

Comment: Add `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());die;` in your `is_login` function outside the `if` condition. Check if `is_logged_in` is printed out.

Comment: `if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != TRUE)` always return true, and redirect to login.

Comment: What value `$is_logged_in` can have?

Comment: I fix it. Now I have:                                         `<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('is_login'))
{
    function is_login()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $logged_in = $CI->session->userdata('logged_in');

        if (!isset($logged_in) || $logged_in != TRUE) { 
            redirect('login');

        }   
    HERE

    }   
}`                                                                  I want to in "HERE" refresh actual page, but I dont know what do?

Comment: ci sessions causes problems when stored in database. i would suggest you to first test your code with cookie storage and then move to database storage following some good tutorial.

Comment: If you want to refresh the actual page check this link out http://www.crashcoder.com/how-to-refresh-current-page-in-codeigniter/